# What is a user friendly thermostat

Tags: thermostat

Currently have chronotherm iv plus. My dad struggles to use it and so do I for his birthday I’m getting him a new Theo What’s a good replacement?

Comment: I like the ones that you only set one temperature and walk away.  The round honeywell's always work well.

Comment: Any basic traditional non-setback thermostat will be easy to use, but you won't get the energy savings you would from one with a schedule.But ease of use us very subjective, and what's available in fancier units changes continuously, bit of which make this out of bounds. Find stores which are set up to demonstrate, or see if friends have something you like. Units which are set from phone may be less *or* more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

### NEVER select tech for other people

Just stop.  Seriously.

It's the biggest cliché in tech that a techie (who self-identifies as "smart") shoves technology down the throats of family - it's the "lack of people skills" thing which is part of the cliché.  Of course the recipient has not "bought in", isn't in favor of it nor comfortable with it, doesn't want to break it, and doesn't want to learn.

So 90% of this game is emotional.  The answer is to start with the human, and ask them what they're comfortable with or like.   Chances are it won't be one of those "battery programmable thermostats", because **the user interface is godawful** - made so by heavy compromise on battery consumption and cost-shaving on display, buttons etc.

The game Cities: Skylines II is revamping how citizens use the roads. Young people go for the cheapest route (will madly zig-zag to save gas/avoid tolls), career adults go for the fastest roads (will zig-zag to pick up freeways), and **senior citizens go for the most convenient** (won't zig-zag).  I think that's very apt, and it goes to show how "what we want" isn't "what they want".

**So talk to the person and ask them what they like, what they've heard, and what they'd prefer**.  It could be that they just want a simple turn-the-knob thermostat like they grew up with, and are not losing any sleep over the energy savings of a programmable thermostat.  It could be that they would like a smart 'stat, but are holding out for a Nest so they can use the UX on an app on their phone* , instead of the hideous, unusable UX of that thing they have now. You don't know til they ask.

* And by 'phone' I mean iPad**. An iPad is the perfect answer to a senior-sized, large-print "phone". That and a flip phone for *actual* calls - that also solves the UX problem of trying to use apps on a phone that you're presently talking on, which is particularly hard for non-techies to navigate.

** and by 'iPad' I mean maybe Android, but **the platform THEY like**, not the platform ***you're*** a fanboy of. If in doubt, buy iOS, and I'm not telling you anything you don't already know lol.  I use both constantly, and yeah - no comparison for a reluctant novice. Many Android apps are redundant (two app stores?), useless, or shovelware.

Comment: Not "never". When my Dad was in his later years, but before he couldn't be on his own, it was *definitely* up to me & my brothers to select tech for him. And thermostats in particular are a good example with a *lot* of older, not tech savvy people. (Plenty of older people *are* tech savvy, but plenty of them are not, *at all*.) I had a call from an older neighbor (early 80s?) who is staying with a friend temporarily and even though it turns out the thermostat was actually about as easy as it could be (electronic setback, etc. but in "Hold" so you could use Up/Down to set) he called me to help

Comment: because it was different from the thermostat in his previous home and he was worried that he would hit the wrong button and mess something up. As a *general* rule, you are correct - trying to guess what computer, phone, thermostat, TV, etc. someone else (friend or relative) will like is *mostly* a pointless exercise. But there are exceptions.

Comment: I miss the mercury switch thermostats.  So simple use.

Comment: @crip659 Those are readily available and cheap.  No promises on mercury content, though.